# I want to list the users connected to this application and send a message

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

There is a chat application related to c# websocket,

I want to list the users connected to this application and send a message to the connected user from the listing section, how can I do it?

[image]

I want to list the connected users next to the "Gönder" and "Çıkış" buttons and send a message to the user I selected from the list.

WebChat.Server

WebChat.cs;

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using WebChat.Core;
using WebSocketSharp;
using WebSocketSharp.Server;

namespace WebChat.Server
{
    public class WebChat : WebSocketBehavior
    {
        private string Header(string id = null) 
            => string.Format("{0} - {1}:", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("hh:mm tt"), id ?? ID);

        protected override void OnOpen()
            => Console.WriteLine($"İstemci Başarıyla Bağlandı: {ID}");

        protected override void OnClose(CloseEventArgs e)
            => Console.WriteLine($"İstemci Bağlantısı Kesildi: {ID}");

        protected override void OnError(ErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {e.Message}");
            Console.WriteLine($"EXCEPTION: {e.Exception}");
        }

        protected override void OnMessage(MessageEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Mesajın Alındığı Sunucu {ID}: {e.Data}");
            ParseJson(e.Data);
        }

        private void ParseJson(string json)
        {
            var request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
            var op = (OpCode)request.Op;

            switch (op)
            {
                case OpCode.Hello:
                    var output = new StringBuilder()
                        .AppendLine(Header("Server"))
                        .AppendFormat("Giriş yapmış {0} kullanıcı var!", Sessions.Count).AppendLine()
                        .AppendLine();

                    foreach (var session in Sessions.Sessions)
                    {
                        if (session.ID == ID)
                            continue;

                        output.AppendLine(session.ID);
                    }

                    Send(output.ToString());

                    Sessions.Broadcast($"{Header("Server") + Environment.NewLine}Kullanıcı Sunucuya Katıldı ID: {ID}");
                    break;
                case OpCode.Message:
                    var msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(json);
                    Sessions.Broadcast(Header() + Environment.NewLine + msg.Text);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs;

```
using System;
using WebSocketSharp.Server;

namespace WebChat.Server
{
    class Program
    {
        public static readonly WebSocketServer ServerSocket = new("ws://localhost:9876");
        public static bool disconnectRequested = false;

        static void Main()
        {
            ServerSocket.AddWebSocketService<WebChat>("/webchat");

            ServerSocket.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Sunucu Başladı! Sunucuyu durdurmak için herhangi bir tuşa basın.");
            Console.ReadKey();

            ServerSocket.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Webchat

Program.cs;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WebChat
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new WebChat());
        }
    }
}
```

WebChat.Designer.cs;

```
using System;

namespace WebChat
{
    partial class WebChat
    {
  
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        ///  Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        ///  Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        ///  the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.rtbOutput = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
            this.txtSendMessage = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.btnSend = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnConnect = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // rtbOutput
            // 
            this.rtbOutput.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.rtbOutput.Name = "rtbOutput";
            this.rtbOutput.ReadOnly = true;
            this.rtbOutput.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(936, 491);
            this.rtbOutput.TabIndex = 1;
            this.rtbOutput.Text = "";
            this.rtbOutput.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.RtbOutput_TextChanged);
            // 
            // txtSendMessage
            // 
            this.txtSendMessage.Enabled = false;
            this.txtSendMessage.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 510);
            this.txtSendMessage.Multiline = true;
            this.txtSendMessage.Name = "txtSendMessage";
            this.txtSendMessage.PlaceholderText = "Mesaj Yazın";
            this.txtSendMessage.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(728, 23);
            this.txtSendMessage.TabIndex = 2;
            this.txtSendMessage.KeyUp += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.TxtSendMessage_KeyUp);
            // 
            // btnSend
            // 
            this.btnSend.Enabled = false;
            this.btnSend.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(746, 509);
            this.btnSend.Name = "btnSend";
            this.btnSend.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(98, 23);
            this.btnSend.TabIndex = 3;
            this.btnSend.Text = "Gönder";
            this.btnSend.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnSend.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.BtnSend_Click);
            // 
            // btnConnect
            // 
            this.btnConnect.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(850, 510);
            this.btnConnect.Name = "btnConnect";
            this.btnConnect.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(98, 23);
            this.btnConnect.TabIndex = 4;
            this.btnConnect.Text = "Bağlan";
            this.btnConnect.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnConnect.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.BtnConnect_Click);
            // 
            // WebChat
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 15F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(960, 542);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnConnect);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnSend);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtSendMessage);
            this.Controls.Add(this.rtbOutput);
            this.Name = "WebChat";
            this.Text = "WebChat";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox rtbOutput;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtSendMessage;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnSend;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnConnect;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have most of the code.  See source : https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp/blob/master/websocket-sharp/Server/WebSocketBehavior.cs.  You need to enumerate through the sessions [foreach (var session in Sessions.Sessions)] and then use one of the SEND method in the source code to send to each session.